# Extended WPF Toolkit - Binding Text of richtextbox

Tags: wpf, binding, toolkit

I am newbie in WPF. I need make TwoWay and OneWayToSource bind to string variable. I want use richtextbox from Extended WPF Toolkit ,because I think it is the easy way.

So I try use richtebox from this library in xaml, code is here:

```
<Window x:Class="PokecMessanger.ChatWindow"
        xmlns:extToolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit.Extended"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        Title="ChatWindow" Height="429" Width="924">

///...

        <extToolkit:RichTextBox Name="rtbRpText"  Text="{Binding _rpText, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Grid.Column="0"></extToolkit:RichTextBox>
```

In code behind, I have this code:

```
    private string _rpText = string.Empty;

    public ChatWindow(PokecCommands pokecCmd)
    {
        rtbRpText.DataContext = _rpText;
    }
```

Problem is, if I wrote something in richtextbox, variable _rpText is still empty, where can be problem?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried typing something and then shifting focus off the `RichTextBox`? I suspect your property will then be updated. If you want to update the property as you type, you'll need:

```
Text="{Binding _rpText, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Comment: it doesn’t work, I bind property text of richTextBox to variable string, no to string property, your solution work only if I bind to string property of class implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: How would you expect it to work if there's no property change notifications?

Comment: Sory, I don’t know. So this interface is a condition.

Answer (score 0):

Kent is correct.  Your properties MUST impement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface for data binding to work properly in WPF/Silverlight.

The [documentation](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=RichTextBox&referringTitle=Home) explains how to bind your property to the RichTextBox: